# linux CFS schedular: if the task is scheduled based on vruntime then how task priority is used for scheduling

Tags: linux-kernel, scheduler

linux CFS schedular if the lowest run(vruntime) task is scheduled then how task priority is used for scheduling or is not used at all.

Runnable task are added to rbtree with vmtime as key and lowest vmtime task wil be left most which will scheduled. If this is the case how priority of task is used for scheduling of task.

Thanks in advance.
Ramesh

Comment: I think priority of process is part of vruntime calculation. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19181834/what-is-the-concept-of-vruntime-in-cfs

Answer (score 0):

I think priority of process is part of vruntime calculation. Refer 
[What is the concept of vruntime in CFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19181834/what-is-the-concept-of-vruntime-in-cfs)

Specifically look at following code in `calc_delta_fair()`

```
    delta_exec_weighed = delta_exec * (NICE_0_LOAD / curr->load.weight)
```

The tasks with high priority(lower nice values) will get larger weights, so the vrumtime accounted for them will be smaller. Refer figure 2.18 and text around it for more details.