# VRUNTIME variable maximum value in minutes / hours

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, scheduler

VRUNTIME is described as the variable in the sched_entity structure that tracks time (nanoseconds).

1. Is this a 64 bit value ? If so what is the maximum time in minutes / hours this variable can hold.
2. With the min_vruntime value, is it to be understood that any new task that is added to the run queue has its vruntime set to this variable ?

I am a bit confused and clarification of these points will be appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the concept of vruntime in CFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19181834/what-is-the-concept-of-vruntime-in-cfs)

Comment: @P__J__ Thanks. I already had a read at that Question and it does not answer my question. Like the person who asked the question, i am also reading the book "Linux Kernel development". There is no explicit answers to clarify the answers i am looking for. Eg. A further clarification of point 1 is needed to understand how frequent v_runtime overflows (Basically how many hours can be encoded in its varibale).

Comment: @P__J__ Brilliant answer !! Why didn't i think of it . SMH